# Excel VBA Userform using vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a userform with 1 combobox and 3 textboxes.  I want to use vlookup to display the values in the texboxes based on the selection in the combobox. The first textbox works but after that it gives errors.  Pls help.
Here is my code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Description = Application.VLookup(ComboBox1.Value, Range("A1:B17"), 2, 0)
    TextBox1.Value = Description
    Platform = Application.VLookup(ComboBox1.Value, Range("A1:B17"), 3, 0)
    TextBox2.alue = Platform
End Sub
```

Comment: this part `Application.VLookup(ComboBox1.Value, Range("A1:B17"), 3, 0)` returns an error, since you want to return the 3rd column, when you defined the range with only 2 columns (` Range("A1:B17")`)

Comment: Also, you have typing error: `TextBox2.alue = Platform` - you missed 'V' in `Value`.

Comment: Please do some basic error checking before posting a question here. Your problem arises simply because you have typos in your code. Voting to close this question as low quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments when you refer to 3. column, you should have at least 3 columns in your range. [Read more about `VLookup` here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1).

Try like this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    Description = Application.VLookup(ComboBox1.value, Range("A1:C17"), 2, 0)
    TextBox1.value = Description
    Platform = Application.VLookup(ComboBox1.value, Range("A1:C17"), 3, 0)
    TextBox2.value = Platform

End Sub
```